# what is this mysterious character in kernel main function? How can i remove it?

Tags: gcc, terminal, x86, kernel, osdev

I am trying to create my own kernel following the link https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones
the author has mentioned that " followed by some mysterious character. "
Why is this character occurring? How can I remove it?

I am using the kernel.c file, just changed the kernel main to print ASCII char.

```
void kernel_main(void) 
{
    terminal_initialize();

    terminal_writestring(" ____                         ___  ____");
            terminal_putchar('\n');
    terminal_writestring("|  _ \\ _   _ _ __ ___   __ _ / _ \\/ ___|");
            terminal_putchar('\n');
    terminal_writestring("| |_) | | | | '_ ` _ \\ / _` | | | \\___ \\");
            terminal_putchar('\n');
    terminal_writestring("|  __/| |_| | | | | | | (_| | |_| |___) |");
            terminal_putchar('\n');
    terminal_writestring("|_|    \\__,_|_| |_| |_|\\__,_|\\___/|____/");
            terminal_putchar('\n');
}
```

Here is my result
[image]

Comment: Please post the code for `terminal_writestring()`, but I think the problem is that it writes `'\r\n'` instead of just `'\n'` at the end of the line.

Comment: The problem is that the odd symbol is the character associated with `\n` (LINEFEED). The character set is [CodePage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#/media/File:Codepage-437.png). It is clear from the output that your code treats `\n` as `\r\n` (line feed and carriage return) as you have it going to the first column of the next line. If that is the behaviour you want then all you have to do is update the cursor position but throw away the `\n` rather than print it. Your code is currently printing the `\n` AND updating the cursor to the beginning of the next line.

Comment: Other characters that you don't want to directly print to the screen - TAB(\t), Carriage Return(\r), Line Feed (\n), Backspace(\b). All of these have to be specially processed.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the terminal_putchar function?

Answer (score 0):

@Ken Y-N is correct in that you should be writing a `\r\n` instead of `\n` (i.e., CRLF instead of LF).

However, a better solution (in my opinion) would be either:

a) to check if the character is `\n` in `terminal_putchar`, and if it is just set `terminal_column` to 0 and increment `terminal_row` by one.:

```
void terminal_putchar(char c) 
{
    /* check that the previous character wasn't a '\r', if it was print CRLF as normal */
    if (c == '\n' && terminal_buffer[terminal_column * VGA_WIDTH + terminal_row] != '\r') {
        /* move cursor to start of next line (without printing a CRLF) */
        terminal_column = 0;
        terminal_row += 1;
        return;
    }
    terminal_putentryat(c, terminal_color, terminal_column, terminal_row);
    if (++terminal_column == VGA_WIDTH) {
        terminal_column = 0;
        if (++terminal_row == VGA_HEIGHT)
            terminal_row = 0;
    }
}
```

or even better b) check if the character is `\n` in `terminal_putchar`, and if so print a CRLF:

```
void terminal_putchar(char c) 
{
    /* turn LF -> CRLF if missing CR */
    if (c == '\n' && terminal_buffer[terminal_column * VGA_WIDTH + terminal_row] != '\r') {
        terminal_putentryat('\r', terminal_color, terminal_column, terminal_row);
    }
    terminal_putentryat(c, terminal_color, terminal_column, terminal_row);
    if (++terminal_column == VGA_WIDTH) {
        terminal_column = 0;
        if (++terminal_row == VGA_HEIGHT)
            terminal_row = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT: For some extra optimization, you could detect a `\r` and set some boolean usable value (for example an int that is either 1 or 0), then replace the `terminal_buffer[terminal_column ...` with the name of that boolean usable value. This allows for guaranteed 4 byte aligned access which is always faster (see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/328775/how-important-is-memory-alignment-does-it-still-matter) for more info). Sample code:

```
uint8_t was_cr = 0;

void terminal_putchar(char c) 
{
    /* turn LF -> CRLF if missing CR */
    if (c == '\n' && !was_cr) {
        terminal_putentryat('\r', terminal_color, terminal_column, terminal_row);
    }

    /* at this point was_cr has already been read */
    /* considering that was_cr is read every time this function is called, */
    /* it is likely that the CPU will cache it's value, so read times will be short */
    /* even if it isn't cached, memory reads are always faster than memory writes */
    if (c == '\r' && !was_cr) was_cr = 1;
    else if (was_cr) was_cr = 0;

    terminal_putentryat(c, terminal_color, terminal_column, terminal_row);
    if (++terminal_column == VGA_WIDTH) {
        terminal_column = 0;
        if (++terminal_row == VGA_HEIGHT)
            terminal_row = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the real key to the problem is what @MichaelPetch pointed out in comments: when you detect a newline, you have to *not* copy it to the screen, *only* move the cursor.  You don't mention that in the text of your answer, just one small comment in one code block.  IMO if you're not going to include the `\n` in the string, you could have a separate function for terminal-newline that didn't have to check anything, just reset column and incremented row.  If you do want to handle `\n` in writestring / putchar, then take advantage of that in the caller.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi, thanks I got the idea, I am literally printing "\n", how do i omit the escape sequences(\n, \r, \t etc) and process my code as usual? do i use the string features etc? - copy strlen -2(\n) to buffer, and then print the buffer?

Comment: @varun_koganti: Obviously the easiest thing is to loop strings 1 byte at a time and check for special cases, otherwise fall through to just copying the character and updating the column.  e.g. have writestring call putchar for every char separately.  That will handle cases where there's a `\n` or `\r\n` in the *middle* of a string. If you want to optimize and still be able to copy multiple bytes at once, you could use SIMD (MMX or SSE2 `pcmpeqb` / `_mm_cmpeq_epi8()`) to check multiple bytes at once for being in the printable-ASCII range, if you enable SSE instructions. (Normally kernels don't)